# Input port 8051

Tags: microcontroller, interface, 8051

I have a microcontroller kit and I am using a 8051 microcontroller. The IC is P8951RD2.

My questions are:

1. All of the pins of all the ports are pulled up by resistors. Port 0 I can understand that it does not have an internal resistance, why is it done for other ports?
2. To make a port input we have to assign a 1 to it. Doing so makes that pin he "high", so outputting 5 V. if I write a program like

   ```
   if(p1.0 == 1){  
     r1=1  
   }  
    else  
    r1 = 0;
   ```

first the 'if' condition will execute, but when we put GND to the pin, the else part will execute.

3. Now I have made some changes: We have not set P1.0 to 1 (that means we have not made it as a input port). I tested this programme and it worked fine: when we applied 5 V to that port the if part is executed and when we remove the 5 V the else part is run.

   Now what I have read is that in order to make a pin input we should assign it as 1 to that and I have not done this in 2nd programme. Is it safe to make an input port low or what else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ever heard of punctuation? Your last section is very very hard to read or understand.

Comment: I have made the changes please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly about the 8051. But usually, a µC has at least 2 registers concerning ports:

1. The DDR (Data Direction Register) which controls the output behaviour of the port. In "input mode", the driving part of the pin is put into High Impedance mode (High-Z). That means the µC does not influence the signal on the pin. Reading from this port/pin thus shows the voltage from putside. In "output" mode, the port outputs whatever the port register is set to. Different platforms may have different mmeanings in this register - some put it into HighZ if writing 1, others put it in output mode.
2. The port register which, when writing to, sets the port to low or high state - if it is in output mode. Reading from it will read the port's state.

But, as I read now about the 8051, I notive that there is an even simpler way where *one* register is enough. This seems to be the case with 8051:

- Writing 1 to the register sets the pin to High-Z. The integrated pull-ups pull it up to High state, but an external source may clamp it hard to Low or High. That is what can be read out of the regsiter then.
- Writing 0 to the register sets the pin to Low. This overrides the pull-up resistors and pulls the port down to GND, making it a low state.

This evidence (which I found by a 2 minute web search) makes me able to answer your questions:

1. What I wrote above is exactly the reason for (internal or external) pull-up resistors: if you don't have them, you cannot make the µC output a High state.
2. The program you wrote (whose `p1.0` syntax confuses me, nut that seems to be just a very specialised C dialect) checks the state of the pin. If you don't apply a source to it, it reads its own pull up and thus always returns 1, except if you manually pull it to 0.
3. I have no idea why that happens - probably the source where you get the 1 from is stronger than the µC's 0 source so that the latter gets overridden by the former one. *Don't do that, however.* It may destroy your pin drivers. You are only supposed to apply an external signal if you don't let the µC pull it to 0!

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about Pull Up Resistors first: 
[this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pull-up-resistors) nice article on SparkFun explains it perfectly:

> Let’s say you have an MCU with one pin configured as an input. If
>   there is nothing connected to the pin and your program reads the state
>   of the pin, will it be high (pulled to VCC) or low (pulled to ground)?
>   It is difficult to tell. This phenomena is referred to as floating. To
>   prevent this unknown state, a pull-up or pull-down resistor will
>   ensure that the pin is in either a high or low state, while also using
>   a low amount of current

That means, Pull-ups are mainly used to keep a pin in "Known state".

In 8051, Port 0 have a dual functionality - It can serve as GPIO and as Address Lines (A0-A7). Note that Address Lines are always Output for a *Master* hence there are no Pull-ups for those lines. Port 2 is also part of Address lines (A8-A15) but it is multiplxed as Data pins too (D0-D7) which can be input or output, so it have Pull-ups.

It is always advised to use external pull-ups if you are planning to use P0 as Input.

Every pin is connected to a Pull-up and a FET (In case of Port 0, just FET). When you clear the pin to make it output, the FET gets turned ON and drains all initial current and brings it to "reset" state (i.e. 0).
When you set a pin to make it Input, FET is turned OFF to connect the pin directly to VCC through Pull-up and brings it known state (i.e. 1).

To summerize, Applying 0 and 1 is to bring the pins to known state... and that's what we mean by "Initialization".

Your 3rd point - It depends on which variant of 8051 you are using. In case of older versions (which are are out of production now) this would have rendered in undefined behavior, and your program is running by fluke! :-)
Newer variants of 8051 come with "[Quasi Bidirectional Ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-bidirectional_I/O)" which means they can act as  Input or Output without pre-configuration.